# Fortran "write" column limit?

Tags: fortran

I am new to Fortran and am trying to write some numbers to a file.  However, every time the output files are created, they refuse to write more than 10 columns. Is this a limit of "write" than can be formatted to allow more columns (at least 12 in this case).

```
        do i=1,113,4
          y(i)=i*dsqrt(3.d0)/2
         do j=2,118,2
         x1(j)=j-0.5
         z1=y(i)+dsqrt(3.d0)/2
         z2=y(i)-dsqrt(3.d0)/2
         x2(j)=x1(j)+a
         x3(j)=x1(j)+3.d0*a
         x4(j)=x1(j)+4.d0*a
         write(227,*) x1(j),y(i),x2(j),z1,x2(j),z2,x3(j),z1,x3(j),z2,x4(j),y(i)
         enddo
        enddo
```

Comment: What is 227 in `write(227,8)`?

Comment: Just the file that I'm writing to; further up in the code (not displayed here) I have 
`open (unit=227, file='hex2.dat', status='unknown')`